# Displaying filtered data on a page from a List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, filter, sub-site

**Current Scenario is as follows**:

I have a parent site where I have a list containing multiple projects with project codes. There can be multiple projects against a project code. The same depicted below in the screenshot:

[image]

Here every **Project Code** will have a specific page(SiteUrl will specify this page). I will have to display data from only those projects specific to each project code. As depicted in the following screenshot:

[image]

**Note**: The second screenshot has values in a calculated column, concatenated columns 'Project Name' and 'Project Code'. The point is I have just added these statically just to share the screenshots. How could I achieve it in real time in SharePoint? That is a list at 'Parent Site', data at all the pages at subsite pages getting updated(filtered according to Project-Code). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I will add the calculated column in the Projects List, and create view to show the column that only match current site. Or you can easily achieve this via CSWP

Comment: Its Better to use SPD workflow on Projects List, which runs on item added/Updated event & add entry in Project-Hub List.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this can't be done "out of the box", as the lists reside in different sites. However, you could copy data across using a workflow or an event handler, the trigger for either case being when an item in the first list is updated.

Comment: could you please share some good tutorials for Event receivers, I am still unable to figure out how to develop and use them.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx